# Error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, authy

I installed authy using the snap install authy command. When I try to open the application, I get the following error message:
`/snap/authy/6/authy: error loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: unable to open shared objects file: No such file or directory`

`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

Answer (score 2):

Installing libx11-6:i386 worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
```

after that I experienced another error solved by installing libstdc++5:i386:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

Comment: 0.709 E: Unable to locate package libx11-6:i386
0.709 E: Unable to locate package libstdc++5:i386
0.709 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++5'

Answer (score 0):

This [forum poster seemed to have the same issue as you](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/parallel-instances-breaks-content-snap-consumers/22774). There was quite a lot of process that they went through, but the thing that fixed it in the end was rebooting the machine.

Are you running parallel installs and does a reboot fix the issue for you?

Comment: I have restarted my machine countless times and it doesn't work, the truth is I think I am learning to live with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lots of things online to solve this - nothing worked until I came across [this comment](https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/62#issuecomment-782568815):

```bash
apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget -y
```

It's very unlikely that all of those are needed, but it works. I'm running in Docker, so there was no risk of messing up my environment - be careful if you're not!